# How can I split a concatenated string to a new column

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have a column that contains concatenated string. I want to split them to a new column.

[dataset that I'm using](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/antoinekrajnc/soccer-players-statistics)

| Work Rate |
| --- |
| Medium / High |
| Medium / Medium |
| Medium / Medium |
| High / Medium |
| Medium / Medium |
| Medium / Low |
| Medium / Low |
| Low / High |
| High / High |
| Medium / Medium |
| High / Low |

I found something like that. But it does not create a column. Also, as a second question, can I create a column from a query like this one?

```
SELECT *,split_part("Work_Rate",'/',1) as attack_work,
split_part("Work_Rate",'/',2) AS defence_work FROM "Football";
```

Comment: why not make a new table. Eslse you need to alter the tables with the new columns and update the new columns. simpler will be to create a new table with the select that you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE  "Football" ADD COLUMN attack_work varchar;
ALTER TABLE  "Football" ADD COLUMN defence_work varchar;
COMMIT; --Or ROLLBACK; if it fails
```

Then:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE
    "Football"
SET
    attack_work = split_part("Work_Rate",'/',1),
    defence_work = split_part("Work_Rate",'/',2);
COMMIT; --Or ROLLBACK; if it fails
```

Comment: my bad, i am used to add a number, so  missed that thnx